# Is there an "Apply changes" feature when remote debugging with intelij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly, remote-debugging, jpda

When using JPDA remote debugging feature with netbeans there is an "Apply changes" feature. This tries to apply the current code changes in the remote jvm.

Is there such a feature with `intelij idea`? If not, is there any other way to perform this? e.g. via command line?

Answer (score 1):

The HotSwap mechanism in InteliJ Idea lets you reload classes changed during a debugging session without having to restart the entire application.

### Reload single file

> Right-click in the editor tab of the modified file and select Compile
> and Reload File.
>
> You can also configure automatic reloading of classes after they have
> been recompiled using the Reload classes after compilation option in
> Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger |
> HotSwap. Automatic reloading can be enabled/disabled, or you can
> configure it so that the debugger asks you whether to reload the file
> in each specific case.

### Reload all files

> From the main menu, select Run | Debugging Actions | Reload Changed
> Classes.
>
> Recompilation happens automatically if the Build project before
> reloading classes option is enabled in Settings/Preferences | Build,
> Execution, Deployment | Debugger | HotSwap. If this option is
> disabled, you need to recompile the files before reloading (Build |
> Recompile Ctrl+Shift+F9).